# parse-server installation returns error createLiveQueryServer is not a function

Tags: parse-platform, ubuntu-14.04, parse-server

Installing parse-server onto my dev box, I'm getting the following error when working through

```
/z/www/parse-server-example/node_modules/parse-server/lib/index.js:335
            throw err;
            ^

TypeError: ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/z/www/parse-server-example/index.js:55:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:142:18)
    at node.js:939:3

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-83-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server-example package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server-example
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server-example
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /z/www/parse-server-example/npm-debug.log
```

I get the same error whether running nodejs index.js or npm start. I'm following the digital ocean instructions for parse-server installation. Has anyone ran into this issue or have any advice?

Comment: I hit this one too, I think there was just an incomplete commit.  There is a blog post introducing the new feature: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-server-goes-realtime-with-live-queries/, my guess is that something slipped through testing.  Simply disabling that feature will get you past that though.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my sanity. That seems to be it as today it went just fine. I get so on the fence when I run into an issue, not sure whether it's my own environment or bug :)

Comment: Have you found any docs on authentication?  I seemed to have missed the memo on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193834/parse-server-authentication-model

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide and it works great, I prefer to use the parse-server and not the example version, all the environment variables are now supported so I would suggest to just follow the tutorial (U will not create a index.js but you will do it with ecosystem.json)

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with a commit the same day I was trying this, works fine now.